# Issues installing a go program

Tags: macos, go

Im new to go and I have been unable to find any thing online for my issue.

I have downloaded this code https://github.com/hashicorp/http-echo and I would like to set it up so I can run this command.

```
$ http-echo -listen=:8080 -text="hello world"
```

I have been getting quite a few different path issues.
Currently I have the code sitting in this directory.

```
/Users/jon/go/src/github.com/hashicorp
```

When I try and install it I get this error

```
$ go install http-echo
can't load package: /usr/local/go/src/http-echo/handlers.go:9:2: non-standard import "github.com/hashicorp/http-echo/version" in standard package "http-echo"
```

Where should I keep go projects on an OSX computer, and how do I get this to install or compile?

Comment: What's the output of `go env`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code currently seems to be in `/usr/local/go/src/http-echo`. Packages should always reside in the directory `$GOPATH/src/package-name`, e.g.: `$GOPATH/src/github.com/hashicorp/http-echo`. (unless you're using [go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules)).

It should work if you move the source to the correct path (`/Users/jon/go/src/github.com/hashicorp/http-echo`). Then execute:

```
go install github.com/hashicorp/http-echo
```

Even easier would be to use `go get` to download the package in the first place. Simply run the following command from any directory:

```
go get github.com/hashicorp/http-echo
```

And `http-echo` is automagically installed.

If you still get an error after this, make sure `$GOPATH/bin` is in your `$PATH`.

Comment: It's `$GOPATH/src/package-name`, not `$GOPATH/package-name`, and only if the [module feature](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) is disabled.